# WebKitWebProcess makes new dock icons

Tags: macos, webkit, webkitgtk

When running a WebKitGTK+ application on macOS, every instance of the WebKitWebProcess makes a new dock icon. Is there a way to disable/fix this behavior?

Suggestions to use lsuielement (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsuielement) have not worked. It seems that WebKit itself and/or GTK is forcing each WebView widget to have a new application icon in the dock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Nyxt Browser](https://nyxt.atlas.engineer/) folks worked this out with some help from WebKitGtk. You need to patch WebKitWebView so that it gets it `NSApp` and calls `[NSApp setActivationPolicy: NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited]`.

Nyxt spread that over several patches and a naked file write in their MacPorts Portfile, I've consolidated it into a [single patch](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk-osx/-/blob/master/patches/0001-Prevent-WebKitWebProcess-from-being-in-the-dock-or-p.patch) for [Gtk-OSX](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/OSX/Building).

Comment: Thank you for answering the question :-). Hopefully it will be useful for future readers!